# Можно ли пережить отсутствие знаков безболезненно?

Tags: пунктуация

> Но ведь не все переживания пусть даже очень красивых людей в очень
>   красивых платьях осмысленны и подходят к случаю, да и просто
>   интересны…

Речь об актёрах в костюмном фильме.

Comment: Так умел только Джеймс Джойс, он бы и оставшейся запятой не простил :)

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем заключается? Нужны ли здесь запятые, или тот,что заявлен в шапке?

Comment: Жасмин меня поняла и ответила весьма и весьма приемлемым вариантом правки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пережить-то  можно, но читается медленно, понимается с трудом,  а это большой недостаток для современной прозы.

Пример редактирования:

**Но ведь не все переживания – пусть даже очень красивых людей и в очень красивых платьях – осмысленны, подходят к случаю, да и просто интересны…**